# Novel: alien with human form with abilities of creation, destruction and transformation, has to kill a list of aliens

Tags: story-identification, novel

An alien with a human form, who has superpowers enabling him to create or destroy things. He can transform himself, and I think he could go back in time for a little (not sure of that last one).

He's around 16 years old. His parents were killed by another alien when he was 5 (I guess).

He has a list of aliens on Earth that he has to kill, ordered by dangerousness, from one as the most dangerous, to the least dangerous.

The guy knows that he is an alien.

He sometimes recreates his friends and his dead parents to chat with them, or ask for advice.

That's pretty much all that I remember of the plot. The novel was already around by 2016, maybe before then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Alien Hunter* (2008) by James Patterson, book 1.5 of the *Daniel X* series.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3202876-alien-hunter#):

> Long ago, **after his parents' brutal murder, Daniel inherited the coveted List of Alien Outlaws and assumed his father's role as Alien Hunter.** With his supreme abilities, like **being able to shape-shift and conjure up long-dead family members out of thin air,** Daniel is ready to take on the scum of the universe.
>
> Number 7 on the list--grand-master of an interplanetary game of destruction that could result in the eventual take-over of earth--is his next target. In a journey that takes him through the bowels of Tokyo and into other realms, Daniel ingeniously tracks the insectile mastermind. But when #7 reveals his true and terrifying powers, Daniel must enlist the help of #7's own son before he finds himself at the center of the most high-stakes game yet.

---

Found with the Google query `science fiction book teenager alien hunts other aliens on earth site:goodreads.com/book`.

Comment: "With his supreme abilities, Daniel can think of nothing better to do than take on the scum of the universe."